# Who owns an NSWindowController, in standard practice?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm seeking further clarification after seeing [What is responsible for releasing NSWindowController objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031715/what-is-responsible-for-releasing-nswindowcontroller-objects)

I'm writing a simple inventory management application for my nephews.  I have a table view that displays the contents of their "library", etc.  To add a new item to the library, they click a '+' button.  This button opens a new window prompting them the details of the item, and validates the input when they click 'OK'.

All of that is working just fine.  However, I have a question about the memory management.  To create the new window, I use the following code:

```
- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender {
  LibraryItemEditorController *editorController = 
    [[LibraryItemEditorController alloc] 
          initWithWindowNibName:@"LibraryItemEditor"];

  [editorController showWindow:nil];
  // editorController is "leaked" here, it seems.
}
```

I cannot release (nor autorelease) `editorController` at the end of `addNewItem:`, because nothing else is referencing `editorController`; if I release it, the window immediately disappears.  I do, however, want the window controller to be released once its window is closed.  In Apple's [Window Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingWindowController.html), I read the following:

> If you want the closing of a window to
>   make both window and window controller
>   go away when it isn’t part of a
>   document, your subclass of
>   `NSWindowController` can observe
>   `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` or, as
>   the window delegate, implement the
>   `windowWillClose:` method and include
>   the following line of code in your
>   implementation:
>
> ```
> [self autorelease];
> ```

I've used `[self autorelease]` in the `windowWillClose:` method of the window controller.  This works, and doesn't leak memory.  However, it just feels ugly; `addNewItem:` looks like it's leaking memory, and static analysis thinks so too.  *I* know that it's actually taken care of in `windowDidClose:`, but it just feels wrong.  Further, the window controller is now releasing itself without ever having retained itself.  This all goes against the memory management rules I've learned.

My other option is to put an ivar on the parent controller (either an `NSWindowController` or an `NSMutableSet` of `NSWindowController`s) and then watch for the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` in the parent controller and release it in response.  This is cleaner, and is probably what I'll do.  It's also a fair amount more work, though, which leads me to my questions.

Is watching for the `NSWindowDidCloseNotification` the standard way of doing this?  What's the standard way of managing `NSWindowControllers` that are created and destroyed on demand?  Is the `[self autorelease]` way the traditionally-recommended option, and it's only now that we have static analysis that this is a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your window is modal, in which case:

```
[NSApp runModalForWindow:[editorController window]];
[editorController release];
```

Here's one pattern for non-modal windows:

```
@implementation QLPrefWindowController

+ (id) sharedInstance
{
    if (!_sharedInstance)
    {
        _sharedInstance = [[QLPrefWindowController alloc] init];
    }
    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification object] == [self window] && self == _sharedInstance)
    {
        _sharedInstance = nil;
        [self release];
    }
}
```

Then anyone who wants to access or display the window can do so through the `+sharedInstance` class method.  If the window not is already visible, it's created, otherwise they get the currently-visible window.

Comment: I wasn't running it as a modal window, but I think I probably should. the sharedInstance version makes sense for an inspector panel, I think. And if I really needed to have multiple windows open at the same time, it would probably make sense for me to hold onto them directly. This works for me.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is correct, as class methods cannot access instance variables. In this case, the class method "sharedInstance" is attempting to access an iVar called "_sharedInstance". This will fail every time.

Comment: `_sharedInstance` would be a static variable, not an ivar. That's generally how shared instances are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for non-modal situations posted above is not correct because class methods cannot access iVars. I solved this problem by creating a class method (in my NSWindowController subclass called LPWindowController) that looks like this:

```
+ (id) autoreleasingInstanceShowingWindow
{
    LPWindowController *obj = [[LPWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myWindow"];
    [obj showWindow:[NSApp delegate]];

    return obj; 
}
```

The above method returns an instance of LPWindowController with a retain count of 1. It also shows the controller's window. This is important, because otherwise we would have to rely on the caller to call "showWindow:" to make LPWindowController's window appear. If the caller ever failed to do this (which would likely be a bug), the controller would never be released. By forcing the window to display when we alloc/init the controller, we avoid this pitfall.

Next, in IB we set our window's delegate to the LPWindowController class and add this in that class:

```
- (void) windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self autorelease];
}
```

And finally, when we need to create and show our window, we simply use the method below instead of calling "alloc/initWithWindowNibName:" on LPWindowController.

```
LPWindowController *cont = [LPWindowController autoreleasingInstanceShowingWindow];
cont = nil;
```

The second line is important. First, it eliminates a warning about "unused variable cont". Second, it eliminates the danger of a dangling pointer. Once the instance of LPWindowController releases itself, if cont is not nilled out, it will point to garbage memory.

Anyway, that's my recommended approach to this problem.