# Should a NSWindowController release itself in windowWillClose:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a subclass of NSWindowController like this:

```
@interface MyController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate>
...
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification;
@end
```

It is the delegate of his window. Everything work OK.

But, to avoid leaking memory, should I do this in the implementation ?

```
@implementation MyController
...
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    ...
    [self release];
}
@end
```

If I don't do this, when I close the window with the little red close button, windowWillClose: is called, and in Instrument I see that the NSWindow is released but not the MyController...

Is this "the way" of doing it ? Or am I taking risk ?

**Note**: *with Command-W the window and the controller are properly released since I'm catching this action in the AppDelegate, the one that has instantiated all this window & controller and therefore know how/when to release them. But the little red close button performClose: on it's own and the best I have achieved is to catch windowWillClose: as a window delegate...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the NSWindowController to release itself, you should use:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self autorelease];
}
```

The `autorelease` message ensures that the close event is properly processed before releasing the NSWindowController.

Your can also check this [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031715/what-is-responsible-for-releasing-nswindowcontroller-objects).

Comment: Not applicable for ARC anymore.